# Yahoo BOSS Geo api Issue

Tags: yahoo-boss-api

I am new for OAuth and for yahoo apis. My problem detail is as follows:
 In my current project, we have to implement one service class in which, when we pass address, 
it should use yahoo boss geo apis and return longitude and latitude of this address. We are using java in our project.

Till now I have done below mentioned following things:

1. I have added project detail at https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/projects and got Consumer Key, Consumer Secret etc.
2. But till now I didn't submit Billing info.
3. I am trying to run this simple java example given at: http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/codeexamples.html . 
    I using Consumer Key, Consumer Secret which I got after adding my project detail. But when ever I am trying to run this example,
    I am getting status code = 503 which means service unavailable. 2-3 time I have got response in XML also.

Please let me know if I am doing any thing wrong here. Also how can I implement my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue is most likely caused by a set rate limit. The error documentation can be found here:
http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/BOSSv2_APDX.html

Answer (score 0):

In the Yahoo Boss group many people reported receiving 503 errors immediately after opening the account and putting in billing information. After 24 hours the problem went a way.